# Public Transit from Dulles and BWI to Bowie MD Sun. May 2nd AM

Tags: public-transport, washington-dc, maryland

My adult brother and sister are coming to visit a very sick relative tomorrow morning. The public transit advice on Google Maps lists numerous transfers and travel times of 9 to 11 hours.

Start #: Dulles airport, 10 am Sunday May 2nd, 2021

Start #2: BWI airport, 10 am Sunday May 2nd, 202

I would like to pick them up in the Bowie/New Carrolton area but can be flexible.

Are there any public transit routes that take less than 2 hours and have few transfers between transit systems? They will use Uber for part or all of the trip if necessary. I live in Philadelphia and am also visiting.

Comment: Did you try setting the "depart at" option on Google maps to be the correct time? Google maps shows me a 2hr19m connection from dulles and a 2h34m connection from BWI.

Comment: From BWI you can take a MARC train to New Carrollton in about 45 minutes it seems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MARC-Penn](https://www.mta.maryland.gov/schedule/stops/marc-penn) commuter train on Sundays has an 11:15AM departure from BWI ([via shuttle bus](https://www.bwiairport.com/to-from-bwi/transportation/shuttles/bwi-courtesy-shuttles)), arriving Bowie State Station at 11:28 or New Carrollton at 11:36.  If their flight is on time they should make that without difficulty.

If their flight is late, the next departure is at 1:00PM, so they might want to consider Uber as a backup.

From Dulles they could take the [Silver Line Express Bus](https://www.flydulles.com/iad/silver-line-express-bus-metrorail-station) to Wiehle-Reston Metro Station, and take the Silver Line and Orange Line to New Carrollton.  This means two transfers but it's entirely inside the Metro system.  It will be much slower (probably close to two hours) but service is more frequent.